# How to take elements from a list embedded in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list made of lists like :

```
values = [('Part A', 0.1), ('Part B', 0.2), ('Part C', 0.3)]
```

How can I take only the second element from all the lists within the values list without using a "for" loop?

By using the brackets []

`values[0][1]`

It outputs the 0.1 value. But when I do

`values[:][1]`

It outputs both parts of the first list.

Sorry I am a beginner.

Comment: you need to loop, list objects don't have a "vectorized" API.

Answer (score 0):

One way is using list comprehension

```
[item[1] for item in values]
```

Another way is using numpy array

```
np.array(values)[:,1]
```

Comment: When I use the numpy array it outputs the numbers as string type. Is there a way to have them put into the array as int or float?

Comment: `np.array(values)[:,1].astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itemgetter` to extract a specific item from an object. **[list, tuple, dictionary]**

`itemgetter` takes as input **an index or a set of indices**

**Code:**

```
import operator

values = [('Part A', 0.1), ('Part B', 0.2), ('Part C', 0.3)]

all_elements=list(map(operator.itemgetter(0,1),values)) 
second_elements = list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), values)) 

print(all_elements)    #[('Part A', 0.1), ('Part B', 0.2), ('Part C', 0.3)]
print(second_elements) #[0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
```